# PHP resize image API

Tags: php, api, image-resizing

I'm developing IPS 4. I have profile popup:

[image]

The profile cover loads very long, because cover dimensions and size are big. So I've decided to make a PHP API which resizes images to needed size and then displays the resized image.

Is this good idea to make cover upload faster?

Comment: It is a good idea in general. But don't do it each time a page loads. 
It can even be done separately from your website operation, in background. And then use only resized pictures. Does this make any sense to you?

Comment: Like Igor T. said, yes, this will speed up the page. But store the resized image so you don't need to resize it with every request. Also, add Etag or cache headers so the image is also cache by the client.

Comment: I suggest viewing either PHP's [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php) or [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) functions to work with images and resize profile images during storing on server not during loading

Comment: Naturally, smaller images will speed up loading resources. There's lots of server components that resize pictures. You question however is too broad to be answered. Do some research on out-of-the-box resizing tools or try implementing your own through something like ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to populate a 436x85 box with user-provided pictures.

My own digital camera has a 18 MPx sensor that produces 4896x3672 pictures that use around 7 MB when compressed as JPEG. Imagine you display e.g. a dozen profiles per page. That's 84 MB worth of network transfer (more than a typical MP3-encoded music album) for a single page. JPEG compression roughly accomplishes a 1/10 ratio so you can assume 840 MB of RAM just to store the pictures. And they you have the overhead of having the browser resample pictures real time.

On the other size, a 436x85 JPEG can use 8 to 22 KB on average (depending on quality settings).

So if you use the raw pictures uploaded by users, of course it's not going to be fast.

Conclusion: always resize pictures yourself. And please do it only once, it's a heavy process even for your server.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is a good idea to store not only the original image, but the resized ones too, because each time a new user is requesting certain page he is getting this big image, what is basically a waste of transfer and makes user wait what leads to poor user experience.

You should make a script which resizes and saves newly uploaded images to your server and use them instead of these big original ones. But also don't forget that resizing is really *CPU-heavy*, so it would be a good idea to queue this action and not do it instantly during the user's request.